# Joomla 3.9.3 Articles: 500 Unknown column 'a.note' in 'field list'

Tags: articles, database, error-pages

I've updated to Joomla 3.9.3 and now when I open the articles pages, I get this error:

> 500 Unknown column 'a.note' in 'field list'

I've tried to fix the database with the Joomla repair function, but this wasn't possible either because I get another error:

> 1709 Index column size too large

To solve this, I tried the repair function from phpMyAdmin, but I'm not so familiar with this. My first try there did not work.

Looking at the database in Joomla, I get the following errors:

> Table 'DB1805098.#__privacy_consents' doesn't exist
>   Table 'DB1805098.#__action_logs' doesn't exist
>   Table 'DB1805098.#__privacy_requests' doesn't exist

Any other ideas on how to fix this?

Everything else seems to work fine in Joomla.

Comment: Can you show us what you get from `echo $query->dump();`?  Perhaps `#_` isn't being appropriately replaced.  Perhaps there has been an adjustment to the table that is aliased as `a`.  Can you let us know what the `a` table schema looks like?  Are there any extensions or have you done any development that may be impacting things?

Comment: `Index column size is too large` error most probably is coming from not optimal db collation setting. This answer is on Laravel, but it can help you with your problem too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42043205/how-to-fix-mysql-index-column-size-too-large-laravel-migrate

Comment: Thanks for your hints. I'm sorry, but I don't have a clue about database debugging. So, I will try to work through. 
I have no idea where to place the echo command to get the current $query by calling the article page.  I've look for the `a` table in my database, but couldn't find it yet. 
I understand the `Index column size is too large` failure, but without knowing which column causes this, I'm not able to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this issue now a second time on another system and tried to fix it the same way.
I've recognized, that this could be fixed easier:

1. Setup a new local Sytem of Joomla with the last running Joomla version (which was 3.9.3 in this case)
2. Exported the database from the live system and imported it to my local Joomla
3. Repaired all database failures with the Joomla autorepair function.
4. Exported the database and imported it on the live system again (which was already 3.9.11).

Comment: Absolute Last Resort "rebuild from scratch" answer. Shouldn't be the accepted answer.

Comment: It was the only solution that worked for me multiple times without any sideeffects. Other solutions are very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution that worked for me and where I had not to dig into the code and database.

1. Setup a new local Sytem of Joomla with the last running Joomla version (which was 3.6.1 in my case)
2. Exported the database from the live system and imported it to my local Joomla
3. Repaired all database failures with the Joomla autorepair function. On my local system it worked fine.
4. Updated Joomla to the live (server) version.
5. Copied the whole filesystem via FTP from my server and overwrite the local system.
6. Checked for any failures
7. Exported the database and imported it on the live system again.

All problems solved!

Comment: Last resort rebuild-from-scratch approach that requires reinstalling all third-party components manually, and risks ruining everything if you forget about some component before reimporting the database. Counting inevitable mistakes requiring you to start over, fixing a nontrivial site with this method can take up to a week of despair and bleakness.

Comment: No, there is no need for reinstalling all third-party-components on the local or the live system. At least for me everthing worked so far and I didn't cange or reinstall any componenet (module, plugine tec.) anywhere. Of course on a big website I wouldn't feel good with this method. But the thing is, this was my last hope and I haven't found a better solution so far.

Answer (score 1):

go to /administrator/index.php?option=com_installer&view=database
click on fix

Comment: I've already tried this but it quits with the failure `1709 Index column size too large`

Comment: If you tried to fix from the Joomla interface, please clearly express this in your question as an edit.  This will prevent volunteers suggesting it. @PatrickMünster

Comment: We should investigate the `1709 Index column size too large` issue and try to fix it manually in order to help Joomla complete the autofix.